# Tkinter. Не получается сверить ввод пользователя с значением из словаря(dict)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Пишу программу для изучения Английского языка. Программа сама по себе очень простая. Выводятся поочерёдно предложения на русском языке а пользователь должен написать данное предложение на английском.
 У меня не получается сверить ввод пользователя со значением что хранится в словаре. Вот мой код:

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import random, time
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('MyGui')
root.geometry('500x500')

d = {'собака': 'dog', 'кошка': 'cat', 'стул': 'table'}
def foo(*event):
     s = random.choice(list(d.keys()))
     lab.config(text=s)
     data = ent.get()
     if data == d.get(s):
        ent.delete(0, END)
        not_correct.place_forget()
     else:
        ent.delete(0, END)
        not_correct.place(x=250, y=200, anchor='center')

not_correct = Label(root, text='No! it is error')    
lab  = Label(root, text='Demo')
lab.place(x=250, y=10, anchor='center')
ent = Entry(root)
ent.place(x=250, y=50, anchor='center')
ent.bind('<Return>', foo)
but = Button(root, text='Ok')
but.place(x=250, y=100, anchor='center')
but.bind('<Button-1>', foo)
oot.mainloop()
```

Comment: Попробуйте вывести в терминал содержимое обоих объектов, а также их типы. Код не читал.

Comment: Если воспользоваться переменными которы я закоментировал в функции hundler, то втерминале выводится тип str() обоих, но почему-то ..... Я вчера весь день просидел над этим, меня уже тошнит от этого кода.

Comment: Хорошо, а содержимое тоже одинаковое?

Comment: Сократите код до 10-20 строк, в которых, по-вашему мнению, заключена проблема, и поясните, что вы пытаетесь сделать, что ожидаете, что получаете в итоге.

Comment: А лучше всего, сделайте для себя сначала консольное proof-of-concept приложение, проверьте, работает ли оно, и уже после переносите логику на GUI.

Comment: Программа работает, только сравнивает предыдущее отображенное слово с текущим введённым.

Comment: Да да, именно. Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать правильно.

Comment: Я с tkinter ни разу не работал, поэтому конкретно не подскажу, но лучше сначала нарисуйте блок-схему алгоритма приложения, продумайте её, и уже затем реализовывайте. Проблема у вас тут:
`s = random.choice(list(d.keys()))` 
`lab.config(text=s)`
`data = ent.get()`
Вы одновременно выводите вопрос и узнаёте ответ пользователя. Естественно, если пользователь не экстрасенс, он не ответит. Я советую вам реализовать две кнопки и соответствующих функции: вывести слово на экран и принять и проверить ответ.

Comment: Спасибо. С праздником вас!

Answer (score 1):

Решено. Добавил несколько функий и исключил метод lab.config().

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import random
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('MyGui')
root.geometry('500x500')

frm = Frame(root, width=500, height=500)

def clear():
    if frm.winfo_children():
        frm.winfo_children()[0].destroy()

d = {'собака': 'dog', 'кошка': 'cat', 'стул': 'table'}
def foo(*event):
    def new_label():
        s = random.choice(list(d.keys()))
        return s

def handler(event):
    '''Функция которая обрабатывает введенные данные'''
    data = ent.get()
    if data == d.get(nl):
        ent.delete(0, END)
        not_correct.place_forget()
        # Здесь я удаляю виджет чтоб слова в виджете
        # не накладывались друг на друга
        lab.place_forget() 
        foo() # вернуться на исходную)
    else:
        ent.delete(0, END)
        not_correct.place(x=250, y=200, anchor='center')

    nl = new_label()
    lab = Label(frm, text=nl)
    lab.place(x=250, y=10, anchor='center')

    not_correct = Label(frm, text='it is not correct')

    ent = Entry(frm)
    ent.place(x=250, y=50, anchor='center')
    ent.focus_force()
    ent.bind('<Return>', handler)

    big = Button(frm, text='Ok')
    big.place(x=250, y=80, anchor='center')
    big.bind('<Button-1>', handler)


    clear(), clear() # Удаляю/прячу виджеты из предыдущего фрейма

clear(), clear()
labus  = Label(frm, text='Go')
labus.place(x=250, y=10, anchor='center')

but = Button(frm, text='Ok')
but.place(x=250, y=100, anchor='center')
but.bind('<Button-1>', foo)

root.focus_force()
frm.pack()
root.mainloop()
```